# Offline Wordpress Application

Tags: categories, tags, windows, offline

I have to Document some Work and i thought to use WP as a platform to work with others. We have articles, pictures in different categoried and could use the tag function. A Search function is practicle but not neccecary.

So for a website documentation as a wiki it would be a wonderful tool.

Is there a way to get the Site working offline in a simple way so that i can give it to other people on a stick? I would like to keep the Tags and categories working. There is no further interaction with the database so I won't save any comments. The best thing would be some export function.

I have thought about a portable xampp or a crawler (which wasn't working so good)

Or does someone know a better solution for me instead of WP?

Comment: wow, thx for the edit. High quality in here...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check for some other platform. WordPress is made to be live all the time : ) But if you are really keen in doing it in WordPress I can suggest a hard way of doing it. You can use the [JSON-REST-API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) for WordPress and jQuery Mobile to build a mobile app that will run on any browser (not only mobile browser). Thank with cache manifest and localStorage you can preserve the information you want to be offline. But this is really a overkill so it is better to look for another platform.